# Is Nokia mis-using static_cast?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, casting

I've just came across [this example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/layouts-flowlayout-flowlayout-cpp.html):

Scroll down to the bottom of the page, where you will find

```
QWidget *pw = static_cast<QWidget *>(parent);
```

Parent is of type: QObject, which is the Base class of QWidget, so in this case, isnt:
dynamic_cast should be used?

such as:

```
QWidget *pw = dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(parent)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know that you are down-casting from a base to a descendant class (i.e., you know the object is actually an instance of the descendant class), then static_cast is perfectly legal (and more performant).

Comment: @soulSurfer2010: Yes. The cast can be generated at compile-time (it's "static") and thus [little or no] runtime cost.

Comment: I think the performance quote is a red hearring. There is a cost but at that distance it is very small. Unless this is in a very tight loop then you will probably see no difference. Thus by using a dynamic_cast<> you would be adding security into your code (presuming they checked for a NULL pointer). If you know that the object is of the desired type then you have a design issue.

Comment: @soulSurfer: I have not used Qt, So I am not sure but a thought dynamic_cast can only be used with polymorphic classes. Are the classes in this case Polymorphic?

Comment: Yes, parent is QObject and is the base class of QWidget

Comment: @Martin:  Yes, I agree that the performance difference here is miniscule (though not necessarily in the general case, since these things can happen in loops and such).  The difference in demonstration of intention is far more important (as pointed out by Konrad Rudolph below, thus my +1 for him).

Comment: In this situation static_cast<> is the correct cast (as they have already checked the type information). I am just saying that performance should rarely by your criteria for choosing one or the other.

Answer (score 8):

Nope, if `parent` has run time type `QWidget*`, then `static_cast<QWidget*>(parent)` is well defined, and does what you expect. If it has not, then behaviour is undefined.

Contrast with `dynamic_cast`, which has always defined behaviour but which is less efficient, since it has to use run time type information.

A good way to downcast safely in debug mode and quickly in release mode is for instance:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T* down_cast(U* x)
{
#ifdef NDEBUG
    return static_cast<T*>(x);
#else
    return &dynamic_cast<T&>(*x); // Thanks @Martin
#endif
}
```

used like this:

```
QWidget* w = down_cast<QWidget*>(parent);
```

Comment: So basically, If I know for sure(!) that A is a base of B and I have a pointer to A and a pointer to B, I can freely cast A->B with static_cast? so dynamic_cast is only for runtime when I'm not sure if the cast will succeed?

Comment: @soulSurfer2010: if you know for sure the cast will succeed, then yes, you can use `static_cast`.

Comment: One line version of the debug branch `return &dynamic_cast<T&>(*x);`

Comment: Why reimplementing boost::polymorphic_downcast? Also I don't like this "debug-safety" approach: 1) it's just introduces difference in behavior between 2 modes; 2) it's not safer: if you get crash in debug mode, you can just look for core, don't need to unwind stack here, right?

Comment: @Alexander: When the exception is thrown, the program has a chance to do something (catch it at top level) instead of crashing.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: I'm aware of that, thanks. What I can't understand is using different techniques in both debug and release modes. It gives one false sense of security, and also misleading: somebody can think that s/he can actually handle this kind of error in `catch`, while in production you would have crash!

Comment: @Alexander: fair enough. Actually it is better to use `assert` here.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: or even `abort()`, depends on app (no sarcasm!)

Answer (score 2):

Since you’re explicitly asking for mis-use: the opposite is true, it would be a mis-use to have `dynamic_cast` here.

While both are legal, `dynamic_cast` indicates that you (the programmer) are not sure that the cast will succeed, and it is expected that you check the result of the cast to test for success. When you are sure that a cast will succeed, then this is highly misleading. Hence, use a `static_cast` instead. This indicates that the types are always well-known and that the result of the cast is sure to succeed.

Comment: When both are legal, dynamic_cast means that you prefer to fail in a controlled manner, rather than facing undefined behavior, if you're wrong.  (It ain't what you don't know that gets you into trouble. It's what you know for sure that just ain't so. -- Mark Twain)  About the only justification for using static_cast here is that the profiler said you have to.

Comment: @James I disagree. Using `dynamic_cast` when you know that the cast will succeed is misleading. At best it’s as redundant as checking for a null pointer after `new` (without `nothrow`). This has got nothing to do with performance but with writing self-documenting code. It’s widely agreed that use of `dynamic_cast` in itself is already a warning sign of design flaws. Not that it doesn’t have its uses (it does) but these are few and far between.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can ascertain that parent must actually be a QWidget or a derived type of QWidget a static_cast is perfectly fine and gives you additional information that you would lose with the dynamic_cast.

So you can see it as additional documentation - obviously only assuming that the people writing the code know what they're doing (we'll give them the benefit of doubt ;) )

Answer (score 0):

There's no "should be" here. Both will work perfectly fine. The reason to use `dynamic_cast` here would be if you wanted to perform the run-time check of the validity of the conversion. But the author of the code did not feel they needed a run-time check, so there was no need for `dynamic_cast`.

In fact, `dynamic_cast` is rarely needed, because in most cases `static_cast` will do the job. Just as a sanity check on might have added an assertion with a `dynamic_cast` in it, but not as the primary casting method.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, but if your code can know for a fact that the original object is a `QWidget` (perhaps through some other flag), then you can save yourself the time and do a `static_cast` instead. Use with caution.